# Download Extension for Joomla 3.0 with Force Login

Tags: joomla, download, joomla-extensions

I am looking for an extension to my joomla site where users can download pdf instruction sheets, forms, etc from a list of files available. I would must rather it forced them to log into the site to be able to download but I can adjust that by just making the module accessible to registered people only. So that is not a must have.

Anyone knows of any extension like this one? I know JoomlaShine has this extension in their JSN CUBE template but they don't offer it by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Akeeba Release System](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-release-system.html) ([ARS on JED](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/directory-a-documentation/downloads/16825)) is probably the best solution of it's kind and is free to download, we use it on several of ours and our client sites.

You can also combine it with the [Akeeba Subscriptions](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-subscriptions.html) ([AkSubs on JED](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/e-commerce/membership-a-subscriptions/19528)) system to manage site access including integrated access to file downloads.

Of course there are lots of [document download extensions](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/directory-a-documentation/downloads) on the the [Joomla Extension Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org).

Comment: thank you. I tried it out and was extremely complicated. I think I found an easier one to manage (QuickDownloads) Its just not tickling my fancy but it will do. Thanks again